# Moving to Google Tag Manager broke our virtual pageviews

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I recently transitioned my company's websites to Google Tag Manager. Due to the fact that our contact forms don't have unique confirmation pages with unique URLs, we use virtual pageviews to track conversions. The form is submitted, and the page reloads with new content and our conversion tracking codes.

Since migrating to GTM, all of our virtual pageviews stopped working. Now when I submit a form on our site, I get this in the console log:

```
ReferenceError: ga is not defined
  ga('send', 'pageview', '/funnel_G1/premium1.html');
```

Before, we had Universal Analytics loading directly on the page. Now we are loading Universal Analytics through GTM. That is all that has changed and I can't figure out why our virtual pageview scripts no longer work.

This is script that fires on a form completion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  ga('send', 'pageview', '/funnel_G1/premium1.html');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you moved to GTM, you likely also correctly removed all on-page GA code, which includes the standard GA snippet and also the

```
ga('create', 'UA-.....');
ga('send','pageview');
```

code. Removing the GA snippet also removes the creation of the "ga" object, which is why you are getting the error you see. With GTM, you will now need to send in your events and pageviews with tags. So what you could try to do is to push events to the dataLayer that help to trigger tags that fire your virtual pageview. In your specific case, you could do something like this when the form is submitted:

```
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'form complete',
   'vpv': '/funnel_G1/premium1.html'
})
```

and then in GTM, you would need to create pageview tag that is triggered by the event 'form complete', and that also alters the page value to the value of the 'vpv' dataLayer key (ie. /funnel_G1/premium1.html).

Comment: OK. Thanks for the advice. I was hoping to avoid having to rewrite/edit all the virtual pageview scripts because there are 20+ occurrences across our site and, as a .NET static site, changing code on the page requires developers -- which was the whole reason for migrating to GTM in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I totally get it. It's a bit of pain, but I believe in the end, it will be beneficial for all parties as your devs will be less involved in the future.

Comment: Actually GTM by default still creates a ga object, unless you have renamed it in the advanced configuration via the "global function name" setting in the GA tag (the difference is that GTM creates a random name for the tracker, which can be rectified by setting an empty value for the tracker name). So I'm pretty sure there is another problem (can we see an URL ?).

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reminder, @EikePierstorff! GTM creates the ga object, but if you want to continue using the code you have, you will need to prepend the name that GTM assigns to the tracker.

Comment: @nyuen, but then your answer will probably still solve the problem and dataLayer.push is defintively the way to go :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, GTM loads `ga()` function asynchronously. If you call `ga()` before it's loaded, you will run in to this error.

Solution is to somehow wait for `ga()` to be defined, or use `dataLayer.push()`

---

### Edit

The solution we ended up using - we just did not include Analytics in the GA, but included them separately in source. GTM would handle other script icnludes except GA. This solution atleast did not break `ga()` usages throughout our project.